# MediaRecorder - safe outputformat (video container) and codec to record playable video even when a device suddenly turns off

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-video-record

Now I use the next settings for `MediaRecorder` instance

```
setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)

setVideoEncoder(
    if (isHevcCodecSupported()) {
        MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.HEVC
    } else {
        MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264
    }
)
```

If a device suddenly turns off (in case of low battery or other system failures which causes reboots or power off) then a currently recording video won't be playable - a corrupted video file.

Is there any settings for `MediaRecorder` (output format/codec) which will keep a recording video playable even in such cases?

**Update**

Seems WEBM format is playable even when a device turns off, though it's not seekable but at least you can play it in such cases.

But one problem - seems Android doesn't support audio encoding for WEBM output format, we can only do video recording [MediaRecorder WEBM with both video and audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759324/mediarecorder-webm-with-both-video-and-audio)

Also problem with WEBM on Android that `MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint()` does nothing... It works fine with MP4 (avc+aac codecs)